# how to Invoking JSON Web Services with Parameters in liferay 7.4

Tags: rest, liferay-7

i create a Rest service via service builder.

```
@AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled = true)
@JSONWebService
public JSONObject feedback(String jsonInfo) throws SystemException, PortalException {....
```

after deploy, the service can be found in api/jsonws

i try invoke the service, and because the jsonInfo is very long, i cannot pass it as part of url path.

i try pass it as object, just like help doc: [enter link description here](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017899652-Invoking-JSON-Web-Services#object-parameters)

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/snm.record/feedback/+json-info">
   <input type="hidden" name="+json-info" value="test"/>
   <button type="submit" >submit</button>
</form>
```

the service has be called, but jsonInfo always get empty.
and if without plus(+), it is missing.

> {"exception":"Missing value for parameter
> json-info","throwable":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing
> value for parameter json-info","error":{"message":"Missing value for
> parameter json-info","type":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"}}

i do not know what i missed, please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your expected parameter type. Have you tried to change your parameter from "String jsonInfo" to "Object jsonInfo"? If you are trying to pass an object, then you may need to set that parameter to be an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the + from the input name.